# Modify query to get right result using collection_list and concat_ws in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have the following set of data in a table:

```
order_no    channel   
619         Sa        
619         Da        
619         Fa        
882         Fa        
882         Fa        
709         Sa        
709         Da        
274         Da        
274         Da
```

Now, I want to combine the channel based on order no, as below

```
order_no    channel   Required Result   
619         Sa        Sa_Da_Fa          
619         Da        Sa_Da_Fa          
619         Fa        Sa_Da_Fa          
882         Fa        Fa_Fa             
882         Fa        Fa_Fa             
709         Sa        Sa_Da             
709         Da        Sa_Da             
274         Da        Da_Da 
274         Da        Da_Da
```

But I am not getting right results when the channels are same

```
order_no    channel   Actual Result 
619         Sa        Sa_Da_Fa          
619         Da        Sa_Da_Fa          
619         Fa        Sa_Da_Fa          
882         Fa        Fa                
882         Fa        Fa                
709         Sa        Sa_Da             
709         Da        Sa_Da             
274         Da        Da    
274         Da        Da
```

I am using the following query:

```
select order_no, concat_ws('_',collect_set(distinct (channel))) as channels
from table A
```

The problem is collect_set will not have any duplicate values if I use with `distinct`. Is there any other way to write this query?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are doing more work than you need to.

`collect_set()` will eliminate the duplicates anyways, which is why you don't need to use the `distinct` operator.

If you want to have diplicates included, you need to use the `collect_list()` function.

See also the [Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF).

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I do want to use distinct as well as duplicate value on the fly. ie, if there is duplicate value, i want to use it only two times. This is just a sample record. The original record can have 2 or more same values for a give order no.